# Normalised distance measure to compare distributions

Tags: distributions, distance, metric, networks

Network generation parameters are to be optimised to produce spatial networks that match a given degree distribution (discrete: negative binomial) and a given continuous distance distribution (geographic distances to network neighbours: weibull). I need a possibly normalised score [0,1] to measure the distance between the empiric distributions of produced networks and given distribution functions.

Comment: Are you referring to a (network) graph? If so, how can you have a continuous distance? Normally, you would count the number of edges to transverse to get from one node to another.

Comment: Thanks gung. I mean geographic distance in a spatial (social) network. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally opted for the integral-based Hellinger distance since it can be easily scaled to [0,1] and is suitable for discrete and continuous distributions (also the `R` package `distrEx` provides an implementation). A valuable resource regarding the topic is a paper by [Gibbs, A. & Su, F. 2002](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1403865).